# When I have r1, r2 table, How to implement r1 - (r1 – r2) without intersect in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm newbie with SQL query.
r1, r2 is data list.

I want to implement r3 = r1 - (r1 – r2) without intersect.
and - is set operation.
And stuid is check Value to minus.

And I think following SQL Query is work.

```
create table r3 as
select *
from r1;

create table r4 as
select *
from r1;

delete from r3
where r3.stuid in
(delete from r4
where r4.stuid = r2.stuid)
```

(I must use deletee Query twice)

Is it work?

Comment: If it will work? Insert some data and run your queries. Then tell us if it did work.

Comment: @jarlh It is not work. r3 have just same value as initial r1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the overlap between two sets.  How about doing this:

```
select r1.*
from r1
where exists (select 1 from r2 where r2.stuid = r1.stuid);
```

If you want a new table:

```
create table r3 as
    select r1.*
    from r1
    where exists (select 1 from r2 where r2.stuid = r1.stuid);
```